# Python regular expression, repeating data

Tags: python, regex

This seems like a simple task but I have sunk enough time into this to finally ask for help:

I have a long text file in roughly this format:

> Start of test xyz:
>
> multiple lines of blah blah blah
>
> Start of test wzy:
>
> multiple lines of blah blah blah
>
> Start of test qqq:
>
> multiple lines of blah blah blah

I want to grab all the stuff after the "Start of test" deceleration, and this expression gets me about half of what I need:

```
re.findall(r'Start of test(.+?)Start of test', curfile, re.S)
```

The most obvious issue is I'm consuming the start of what I need to search for next, thus yielding approximately half of the results I wanted. Assuming I could avoid that I still can't figure out how to get the last chunk where there is no "Start of test" to end match to.

I assume I need to be using negative lookahead assertions, but I am not having much luck figuring out the proper way to use them, I've been trying stuff like:

```
re.findall(r'Start of test(.+?)(?!Start of test)
```

which gives no useful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the pattern you are looking for

`Start of test(.+?)(?=Start of test|$)`

Then your new code should be

```
re.findall(r'Start of test(.+?)Start of test', curfile, re.S)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY6gR2/5)

Answer (score 0):

You want a lookahead pattern.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html where it describes `(?=`...`)`:

> **`(?=...)`**
>      Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

So for your case:

```
re.findall(r'Start of test(.+?)(?=Start of test)', curfile, re.S)
```

But this will have to be tempered with a non-greedy evaluation.

Comment: That expression gets me 99% there, but it misses the last chunk, how would I resolve that?

Comment: The last chunk will not be followed by "Start of test", so you need to have either `(?=Start of test)` or `$` after the `(.+?)`.

Comment: @user3552664:  Maybe add to the end of the text the string 'Start of test':  `re.findall(r'Start of test(.+?)(?=Start of test)', curfile + "\nStart of test", re.S)`

Comment: @wallyk That's clever, I'll use this if I don't find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more useful to use `re.finditer` to get an iterable of match objects, and then use `mo.start(0)` on each match object to find out where in the original string the current match is. Then, you can recover everything in between matches in the following way -- notice that my pattern only matches a single "Start of test" line:

```
pattern = r'^Start of test (.*):$'
matches = re.finditer(pattern, curfile, re.M)
i = 0  # where the last match ended
names = []
in_between = []
for mo in matches:
    j = mo.start(0)
    in_between = curfile[i:j]  # store what came before this match
    i = mo.end(0)  # store the new "end of match" position
    names.append(mo.group(1))  # store the matched name
in_between.append(curfile[i:])  # store the rest of the file

# in_between[0] is what came before the first test
chunks = in_between[1:]
```